# What method to use instead of Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dQnz.png)

im trying to auth through google and it seems like Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData is no more working.

Comment: Going forward, instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Answer (score 0):

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!){
if let err = error {
    print ("failed to log into Google", err)
    return
}

print("successfully logged into Google",user)
guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else {return}
guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else {return}
let credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)


Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
    if let err = error {
        print ("failed to create with google account", err)
        return
    }
    print("successfuly logged into Firebase with Google", user?.user.uid)
})

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (result, error) in
            if error == nil{
                //use result info and do what you want here
            }else{
                //or other wise print the error description and looking it
                print("This is the Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```